# Setting node selector for spring cloud dataflow task and stream deployments on kubernetes

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We want to fix all our spring cloud dataflow task and stream deployments to a particular set of nodes.

I have this working manually for a sample task eg

```
task launch test-timestamp --properties "deployer.*.kubernetes.deployment.nodeSelector=env:development"
```

(this wasn't obvious as the documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes-deployer seems to imply the key is just nodeSelector not deployment.nodeSelector)

This correctly adds the node selector into the pod yaml for kubernetes.

But I want this to be set automatically ie using `task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default` properties in the SCDF server config.

Ive tried:

```
task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.deployment.nodeSelector: env:development
```

and

```
task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.nodeSelector: env:development
```

but neither seem to work. What is the correct way to configure this?

Same question for stream deployments via skipper.

Also how do I set this up for scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that you've had to try a few options to get to the bottom of finding the right deployer property that actually works.

In general, from SCDF's Shell/UI, the `deployer` token is a short-form for `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes` property. It's a repetitive thing to supply when you have more deployer properties to configure in a stream/task, so we have a short-form for that reason.

However, the `nodeSelector` is not a deployer-level property with a default, though. It is only available as a deployment level property, so that means, it is *only* available as an option for a per deployment basis.

To put it differently, it is not available as an option for "global" configuration, so that's why `task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.deployment.nodeSelector: env:development` is not taking into account. Same also is true for Streams through Skipper, as well.

It can be improved, though. I created [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes#300](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/300) for tracking - feel free to subscribe to the notifications. Both Streams and Tasks should then be able to take advantage of it as a global configuration. Once the PR is merged, you should be able to try it with SCDF's `2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` image.

As for the K8s-scheduler implementation, we do not have support for `nodeSelectors` yet. I created [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-scheduler-kubernetes#25](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-scheduler-kubernetes/issues/25) - we could collaborate on a PR if you want to port the functionality from K8s-deployer.

Comment: K8s-deployer #300 is already in PR state - if you're interested in trying it out, see [here for instructions](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/pull/301#pullrequestreview-255335337).