# Spring batch worker pods getting scheduled only 2 worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes

I am running Spring Batch application in Kubernetes environment. The k8s cluster have one master and three worker nodes. I am testing spring batch under high load, which is spawning around 100 worker pods. However, all the 100 pods are coming up only on two out of three worker nodes. No node selector or additional labeling has been done on the nodes.

I have used Spring cloud deployer Kubernetes to create worker pods in Kubernetes.

The versions involved are:

- Spring Boot: 2.1.9.RELEASE
- Spring Cloud: 2020.0.1
- Spring Cloud Deployer: 2.5.0
- Spring Cloud Task: 2.1.1.RELEASE
- Kubernetes: 1.21

How can I ensure that worker pods get scheduled on all available worker nodes evenly?

Following is the partition handler implementation responsible for launching the tasks.

```
@Bean
public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(TaskLauncher taskLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer) {

    Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(resourceSpec);

    DeployerPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new DeployerPartitionHandler(taskLauncher, jobExplorer, resource,
        "worker");

    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.profiles.active=worker");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.task.initialize.enable=false");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false");
    commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.task.closecontext_enabled=true");
    commandLineArgs.add("--logging.level.root=DEBUG");

    partitionHandler.setCommandLineArgsProvider(new PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider(commandLineArgs));
    partitionHandler.setEnvironmentVariablesProvider(environmentVariablesProvider());
    partitionHandler.setApplicationName(appName + "worker");
    partitionHandler.setMaxWorkers(maxWorkers);

    return partitionHandler;
}

@Bean
public EnvironmentVariablesProvider environmentVariablesProvider() {
    return new SimpleEnvironmentVariablesProvider(this.environment);
}
```

Comment: Please check whether you have taints and tolerations applied to any node ? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/

Comment: No, only the master node have taint for NoSchedule. Worker nodes don't have any taint and toleration applied to them.

Comment: +1 to checking Node affinity of your Pods. If nothing is set at that level, do the nodes have the same resources (ie are you sure k8s can schedule workers on each node)? I'm thinking of one node not having enough resources to get workers scheduled on it.

Comment: All the 3 nodes are of same configuration and no node selector or affinity is being applied.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma What is the cluster setup? Cloud/on-premise? Was it setup using `kubeadm`?

Comment: It is an on-premise setup with kubeadm.

Comment: Have you specified Nodeselector? Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127431/conditionally-launch-spring-cloud-task-on-a-specific-node-of-kubernetes-cluster
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776162/setting-node-selector-for-spring-cloud-dataflow-task-and-stream-deployments-on-k

Comment: No, node selectors are not specified

Comment: @AbhinavSharma Have you managed to resolve this? Maybe try to rejoin the node? If no taints/tolerations and nodeselectors are set up, pods should be scheduled freely. Or you can try to drain one of the nodes so pods will be forced to rescheduled on other nodes.

Comment: Re-joining the nodes seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this out of comments as a community wiki for better visibility, feel free to edit and expand.

---

There are scheduling mechanics which can prevent scheduling pods on some nodes:

- [Taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)
- [Node selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)

If nothing is set, it's worth trying to rejoin the node. For instance it might not be registered correctly (this solved the issue above).